# I added selectRowAtIndexPath in cellForRowAtIndexpath to mark previous selected row but if scroll tablview it crashs

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am making a custom UITableView menu selector component. Every time I selected a specific row, I save this row's indexpath, so the next time when a user to select another row, people can know his previous selected row. So I added this into cellForRowAtIndexpath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = self.left[indexPath.row][@"name"];
    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kPreviousSelectedRow] integerValue] inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    return cell;
}
```

and when the user select another row, save this row to :[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kPreviousSelectedRow], so next time he can see his previous selected row.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row] forKey:kPreviousSelectedRow];
}
```

The crash log: index is [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kPreviousSelectedRow] integerValue] and count is numberOfRows. As you can see, it shouldn't out of bounds. I don't know where the [0...6] come from.

```
2013-08-23 21:01:26.107 [17605:c07] index:10, count:14
2013-08-23 21:01:26.173[17605:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 7 beyond bounds [0 .. 6]'
```

EDITED:And If I scroll the tableview slow, it won't crash, if I scroll it fast, it crashes. what?

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath is called every time the user scrolls new cells onto the screen. Is this really where you want to be selecting your cell?

Comment: I don't have any other option left. It's a subclass of UIView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a crash because at this exact time you have no cell with specified index because you're just preparing it inside your `- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

To get behaviour you're expecting move `selectRowAtIndexPath:` out of `- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and place it inside another method where you're updating your `UITableView`: `-(void)viewDidLoad` or where you call `-(void)reloadTable` for example

Comment: But it's a subclass of UIView, there is no viewdidload.

Comment: Find another place where you already loaded/updated your table.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see your whole file to be able to help you

Answer (score 1):

Your app is crashing because it is trying to select a row that it may not be currently visible. You are trying to select a row in your data source method "cellForRowAtIndexPath" when the data may not be completely available yet. That is why you get the out of bounds error.

For your specific example, you could try to select the previously selected row inside your "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" before you update the value, it will not crash here since your data has been already displayed.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kPreviousSelectedRow] integerValue] inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]     forKey:kPreviousSelectedRow];
}
```

Comment: That is weird, I have the exact same code working. Do you want both rows to be selected? Do you have multiselection set? Are you deselecting the row at any other point?

Comment: Also, make sure your NSUserDefaults are set before calling the selectRowAtIndexPath. You may want to wrap it on an if statement.

Answer (score 1):

SVGreg was right. You should work with cell inside another method. But viewDidLoad not best option. You may try this useful method of delegate

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kPreviousSelectedRow] integerValue] inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kPreviousSelectedRow] integerValue] inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

Shouldn't be inside `cellForRowAtIndexpath`.

Get your `indexPath` from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` which is triggered every time the user selects a cell. 
If you want to trigger another method when the user deselects a cell or selecting another cell use

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

Comment: No, it's not I selectRow in cellForRow, I only using selectRowAtIndexPath to mark previous selected row, so user can know his previous selected option. Then if a user want to select another row, I implement it in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath. What's the better way to mark a user's previous selected row.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a array with the capacity equal to your number of rows. Probally populate it with NO BOOL values (actually [NSnumber numberWithBool:] since they need to be objects).

Then in

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

change the value of the object at position indexPath.row,

And in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

check if the BOOL value from your array is set on YES then select the cell. (cell.selected = YES)

You could go the extra mile and make a custom cell with a custom selection style or something and make a method on the cell that will apply your selected design and call that method in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I just replace selectRowAtindex to layoutsubview, and it won't crash, now. thanks SVGreg's hint.